# Why does a washer need 18" of 2" standpipe?

Tags: plumbing

Code requires minimum 18" of minimum 2" pipe above the tap weir for a washer standpipe.  What is the reason for those dimensions?  Could i use 3" pipe and make my standpipe shorter than 18"?  (8" of 3" pipe has the same volume as 18" of 2" pipe)

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning in terms of buffer size is correct, however you can't use a shorter but wider pipe that ultimately feeds into a 2in through a reducer. The diameter shall never *decrease* in the direction of the flow. Such a constriction would reduce speed and possibly cause build-up or catch debris.

A sink basin (per Ecnerwal's answer) would be a feasible buffer, because you could easily clean out the basin.

So even for non inspected work, I would avoid this if the 3in standpipe were followed by a reducer to 2in plumbing.

I have a suspicion the wording intends to avoid a 1.5in drain in favour of a 2in drain, and it doesn't anticipate a 3in drain. And at 2in, the length must be at least 18in to attain the desired volume.

Comment: It's a clear violation (as you quote) to reduce a 3" input to a 2" pipe downstream. So if you put in a 3" pipe, it's gotta 3" or bigger from that point until the sewer treatment plant. The wording does not bar using a 2-1/2" or 3" pipe - it simply sets minimums.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I am certainly no code expert, and I agree with your reading, but one could wonder why the 18in min applies even for 2.5 or 3in pipe.  When not enough people ask for a certain configuration, it won't be anticipated in the wording. Sometimes it's caution, sometimes it's myopia.

Answer (score 2):

*I suppose my comment is an answer.*

You have stated that your applicable plumbing code requires a **minimum** 18" of **minimum** 2" pipe.

If that's the code language, you can't have *less* on ether point. It does not matter the reason code wants that (primarily sufficient head and pipe size to accept the high-speed flow from the washer) because you can't make *either* of those smaller and pass inspection.

So, since your question boils down to

> *can I do 8" of 3" pipe instead, or something like that*

the answer is that **you can't do that per your applicable code.**

The only generally code-accepted way to get away from the laundry standpipe required size, location, etc. I'm aware of is to have a laundry sink that the washer drains into, and then a simple 1-1/2" P-trap is sufficient - but a laundry sink takes up considerable room itself - which may or may not be a problem for a given install. But it's not a standpipe so the standpipe rules don't apply to it.

Comment: Inspection isn't an issue for me.   I ended up with 12" (above the trap weir) of 3" standpipe pipe feeding a 3" trap reduced to a  2" drain with a 2" vent about 6" down from it.  The peak of  the washer hose is 84" off the floor of the  washer and the washer is spec'ed at  96".  I reasoned that I have plenty of volume up there and the 84" head on the washer pump will slow  down its flow rate anyway.  It works fine.  For safety, I have a water level sensor inside the standpipe that will shut off the washer if the water gets within 3" of the top of the standpipe.